# Balance out balance out exceptions and anomalies

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does this sentence mean?

> Researchers count on large numbers to **balance out exceptions and anomalies..**

Comment: Everyone who suggested closing this question is just a son of bitch because I'm a new member...You really suffer from mental illness

Comment: Undoubtedly the person who gave me a negative score is  a mother fucker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/balance-out) (adjusted) has:

> **balance out** [phrasal verb] [/multi-word verb; transitive or intransitive]
>
> If two or more opposite things balance out or if you balance them out,
> they become [or you make them] equal in amount, value, or effect.

The assumption (based on observation and probability theory) is that positive deviations and negative deviations from the norm will usually counteract each other ('cancel out') in the long run rather than have a cumulative effect. The more observations, the more likely this smoothing effect is, the less the effect of individual outliers ('anomalies') on the broad picture.

If you're looking at a measure of central tendency, say the mean of a set of numerical data, 17 very small outliers may skew the mean appreciably, whereas 17 very small and 15 very large outliers (a more likely scenario) will have a negligible effect. The greater the sample size, the more probable this balancing out is.